# Error while trying to insert data into database (Spring and Hibernate)

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate

This is the error

```
   HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into links (category, xdate, desc, tags, xtime, tittle, url, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into links (category, xdate, desc, tags, xtime, tittle, url, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into links (category, xdate, desc, tags, xtime, tittle, url, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into links (category, xdate, desc, tags, xtime, tittle, url, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:629)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:412)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    com.killerlinks.controllers.LinkformController.save(LinkformController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:412)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    com.killerlinks.controllers.LinkformController.save(LinkformController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10657)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:412)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    com.killerlinks.controllers.LinkformController.save(LinkformController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.33 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.33
```

My Dao Class is

```
package com.killerlinks.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.killerlinks.model.Linkform;

@Repository
public class LinkformDaoImpl implements LinkformDao
{
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void insertLink(Linkform linkform)
    {
        System.out.println(linkform.getTittle());
        System.out.println(linkform.getUrl());
        System.out.println(linkform.getCategory());
        System.out.println(linkform.getDesc());
        System.out.println(linkform.getTags());
        System.out.println(linkform.getDate());
        System.out.println(linkform.getTime());

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(linkform);
    }

}
```

Println statements are working fine, when i dont insert into database.

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(linkform);
```

When i use this statement in above program i am getting error.

My Bean Class is

```
package com.killerlinks.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
    @Table(name="links")
    public class Linkform implements Serializable
    {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="tittle")
    private String tittle;
    @Column(name="desc")
    private String desc;
    @Column(name="url")
    private String url;
    @Column(name="category")
    private String category;
    @Column(name="xdate")
    private String date;
    @Column(name="xtime")
    private String time;
    @Column(name="tags")
    private String tags;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTittle() {
        return tittle;
    }
    public void setTittle(String tittle) {
        this.tittle = tittle;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Linkform [tittle=" + tittle + ", url=" + url + ", category="+ category +", tags="+ tags +", desc="+ desc +"]";
    }
}
```

Please help me out to fix this bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column name `desc` is invalid, because it is revered word in Oracle. Solution is to use other name for column.